# RenderScript problems in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, renderscript

I'm trying to compile a sample of renderScript, but no way. 
I have some errors that I can not solve:

```
[09.22.2014 18:28:44 - aaa] error: Error reading '... \ aaa \ process.rs'
```

Also I get that kind ScriptC_process there when I created the file .rs.

[image: Eclipse error]

project.properties:

```
project.properties:
renderscript.target=18
renderscript.support.mode=true
sdk.buildtools=19.1.0
target=android-20
```

Also show the configuration of the project. Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**

The code of process.rs is as follows:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.aaa)


//multipliers to convert a RGB colors to black and white
const static float3 gMonoMult = {0.299f, 0.587f, 0.114f};

void root(const uchar4 *v_in, uchar4 *v_out) {
  //unpack a color to a float4
  float4 f4 = rsUnpackColor8888(*v_in);
  //take the dot product of the color and the multiplier
  float3 mono = dot(f4.rgb, gMonoMult);
  //repack the float to a color
  *v_out = rsPackColorTo8888(mono);
}
```

I'm just using for example the following website: 
[link] https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html

Comment: The fact that you're getting an error on the ScriptC_process declaration, seems to indicate that the RenderScript reflection layer is not able to parse your process.rs kernel file, so the problem might be in that instead. Can you post a copy or a screenshot of your process.rs script so we can take a look?

Comment: Yes now I edited the post to attach it, just have an example code but no way to make it work.

Comment: Where are you placing the .rs file in your source tree? Are you actually using "com.example.aaa" as you wrote above, or is it something else (perhaps something we can't parse the characters for in the filename)?

Comment: Thanks for the question but I would say that that's not the problem. For example, downloading the Intel project, also I get the same error in ScriptC_process 

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/renderscript-basic-sample-for-android-os

Not because reason is not able to read the file .rs intel or recognize classes. Is there any possible incompatibility with x64 Juno eclipse?

Comment: I have solved the problem. It was due to the path had special characters.